# Django don't save ModelMultipleChoiceField in admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to filter skill_ids  fields and create 3 "abstract" fields for every SkillType, but now it's not saving this hard_skills field in admin site.

Model

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    level_id = models.ForeignKey('Level', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    permission_ids = models.ManyToManyField('Permission', blank=True)
    skill_ids = models.ManyToManyField('Skill', blank=True)
```

Form

```py
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    hard_skills = ModelMultipleChoiceField(Skill.objects.filter(skill_type=SkillType.HARD_SKILL),
                                           widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Hard Skills", False), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        exclude = ['skill_ids']
```

Admin

```py
@admin.register(Task)
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 25
    list_display = ['name', 'category_id', 'level_id', 'get_permissions']
    list_filter = ['category_id']
    filter_horizontal = ['permission_ids', 'skill_ids']
    form = TaskForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        for hard_skill in form.cleaned_data.get('hard_skills'):
            obj.skill_ids.set(hard_skill)
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: The `super().save_model`, will overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

`ManyToManyField` method `set` requires a list, so this should do:

```
obj.skill_ids.set(form.cleaned_data.get('hard_skills'))
```

Comment: I wrote something like this but it's  still not saving
`
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        obj.skill_ids.set(form.cleaned_data.get('hard_skills'))
        obj.save()
`

Comment: If you read [Django documentation example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), the super method should go at the very end and no obj.save() call is needed. But then the question is if the super method modifies the obj based on form and change params, which I am not sure. Then, I would try implementing this in the model's method save() instead of admin's save_model().